# AWS Lambda function query SQS MessageId and ApiGateway

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-api-gateway, boto3

Invoking the url of my Api Gateway triggers a Lambda function that inserts the message passed in SQS and returns the id of the message in the queue.
Now I created another resource of API Gateway and through another Lambda function print all messages in the queue. This is the function:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
    queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='<queue_name>')

    messages = set()
    for m in range(0, 9):
        msg_list = queue.receive_messages()
        for msg in msg_list:

            messages.add(msg.body)

    return list(messages)
```

How can I change the function to get only the message with the specified id?
How can I then configure the Api Gateway to receive this
parameter and pass it to the Lambda function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQS is not a database, you can't "query" it. If you need to retrieve a message by some key you're better off using key-value storage. Both ElastiCache Redis and DynamoDB would be great for such type of work.

Comment: ok but is it possible to get only the message with specific id?

Comment: @xergiopd: i don't see any attributes on ReceiveMessage that would allow you to specify a messageId. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

As Sergey pointed out -- pulling a specific SQS message by ID isn't really a use case that SQS is designed for as it's a queuing system.

Comment: You could store your message with a predefined key in S3 and then pull the message back by that key instead. You could also use DynamoDB or RDS which are both well suited to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @xergiopd In theory, it is possible to retrieve a message with a specific `messageId`. You can start retrieving all messages one by one, but not delete them. Once you received a message with a specific `messageId`, you process and delete it. Other messages will return to the queue after `VisibilityTimeout` window. Now that you know that it is possible, I have to say: this is the most stupid way to process SQS queue in the world.

Comment: ok i understand that i was wrong and thanks for the comments, although the last a bit 'too heavy